# Horizontally Scrolling UICollectionView with Vertically Scrolling Sections

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement the following:

[image]

1. At the top is a segment control that, based on the user's selection (either tapping or scrolling), moves to the relevant CollectionView section.
2. I've been playing around for a couple of days with CollectionViews and maybe I've just confused myself with LayoutFlows and CompositionalLayouts or is that over complicating it?

I have a diffable datasource that is made up of [Sections, CellItems] but I'm struggling with how to structure it.

What is the recommended programmatic (rather than using interface builder) to do the above?  I was just going to originally do 5 horizontal cells, each with a tableView but based on some other comments I've seen from Apple on the Apple forums and the move away from TableView to CollectionView at this year's WWDC, I thought I should be trying to do this properly.

Any direction would be appreciated.  All my research seems to point to using orthogonalScrollingBehavior but that layouts out the sections vertically with each section scrolling horizontally.

So my question is should I be trying to do what I'm doing using a CompositionalLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Well first off your segmented control idea makes this sound like you could just use a page control for the horizontal aspect and remove a lot of the collection view complexity. Something to consider anyway.

As for the data source, I think all you need is an array of arrays. Eg. [[CellItems]]. So `CellItems[0]` would be the first column. Then `CellItems[0][0]` would be the first cell. `CellItems[1][2]`... 2nd column 3rd cell. I do apologize as your current solution may be related to diffable datasources and I haven't had time yet to dig into those.

Start with the horizontal axis first and ignore the vertical axis. Get that working as needed. Once you have that up and running... implement another collection view into the first one's cells.

Sorry if I misunderstood the question if it was more about HOW to implement a collection view.

Comment: Thanks.  That's the direction I was starting to lean towards (collectionViews within a collectionView) I just thought there may have been a way better way so there was onoe dataSource, one collectionView etc.